# Angular2- Using a component from another application

Tags: angular

I m trying to use a component in my app from an other app. My projects are in the same folder so i thought it would work but i m getting "Cannot find module" exception.
Is there a way to do it ? or another way to achieve this ?

What i did so far is :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OverviewPaginationComponent } from './../../../../overview/src/app/overview-pagination/overview-pagination.component.ts';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'combi',
  template: `
 <overview-pagination><overview-pagination>

`,
  styleUrls: ['combi.component.css'],
  providers: [],
  directives: [OverviewPaginationComponent]
})
export class CombiComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And defined in systemConfig :

```
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/combi',
  '../../overview/src/app/overview-pagination',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the Component you are trying to use to the parent Module of that 'feature' where you're going to use the component. For example, assuming this module is the parent module where you're trying to use the OverviewPaginationComponent:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OverviewPaginationComponent } from 'path';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OverviewPaginationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```